# Surface in box2das3

Tags: actionscript-3, box2d, surface, curve

I'm using [box2dflash](http://www.box2dflash.org) for as3 and i need to create curvy ground like this[image: Needed ground].

Facts:

- I can't create one solid object as far as I know because box2d support convex objects;
- I didn't find any line-based objects.

Question:
Is there any better way than doing this the way shown on image below?
[image: maybe bad solution]

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't say for sure, but I think that is the best way of doing it.

There is some code on this article for doing a similar thing:
[Terrain like tiny wings](http://www.emanueleferonato.com/2011/08/03/create-a-terrain-like-the-one-in-tiny-wings-with-flash-and-box2d-adding-a-car/)

You will want to look at the "drawHill" function (Line 91). Sorry I can't be of much more help, I have limited experience with box2D.

Answer (score 0):

I've discovered that you actually can create line.

```
var groundFixtureDef:b2FixtureDef = new b2FixtureDef();
groundFixtureDef.density = 1;
var someShape: b2PolygonShape = new b2PolygonShape();
someShape.SetAsArray( new Array(new b2Vec2(-3,0),new b2Vec2(2,0)), 2);
groundFixtureDef.shape = someShape;
```

This would create a simple line. But if you add more points, it'll form convex shape.